# can't resolve classes with npm pack generated package

Tags: react-native

I am trying to create a library that other team members can install but having no luck. After I do npm pack and install the tgz file to a test app, the following error loads up in the emulator:

```
you likely forgot to export your component. CHeck the render method of 'App'
```

The crush does happen only when I try to use the component, not when importing it. I created the project with just npm init and didn't use any other library, should that matter.

The library is

ColorRoutes.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import RoutePoint from './RoutePoint'
import ServiceProcessor from './ServiceProcessor';

const ColorRoutes = ({
  points
}) => {

  return (
    <>
    <View style={styles.wrapper}>
    
      </View>
    </>
  );
};
export default ColorRoutes;
```

RoutePoint.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';


const RoutePoint = ({
  x,
  y
}) => {

  return (
    <>
    <View>
    
      </View>
    </>
  );
};
export default RoutePoint;
```

ServiceProcessor.js

```
class ServiceProcessor {
  
    generateRoutePoints(points){
        //.....
    }  

  }
 
export default ServiceProcessor;
```

index.js

```
import ColorRoutes from './ColorRoutes';
import ServiceProcessor from './ServiceProcessor';


export {
    ColorRoutes,
    ServiceProcessor,
  }
```

now in my test application, after installing the package, I am doing:

```
    import { ColorRoutes } from 'packagename'
```

hovering over ColorRoutes does show the signature of the component and the app doesn't crush but if I try to use the component like:

```
         <ColorRoutes points = {points}/>
```

it crushes.

For sanity, I created App.js in the library itself and imported ColorRoutes and it works well but not after I do npm pack to be used in other library.

Answer (score 0):

oh that extra comma in index.js was the issue.